# Ruby on Rails Test Email Uniqueness Inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble finding an efficient asynchronous method to test whether an email that a user enters is unique. I don't want to use validates within my controller because I want to present a popup before the user submits the form.

I'm basically trying to do User.find(:all, :conditions => ["email == ?", current_user.email]) but from within the javascript on my html page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this:

- A method in your controller that checks email uniqueness, like `unique = (User.find(:all, :conditions => ["email == ?", current_user.email])).length == 0`. Let it just return JSON like this: `render json: unique`. No need for a view.
- A route to that method.
- A function in JavaScript that sends an email to the above route and gets a JSON document in return.

Here's an untested example using jQuery:

```
function isEmailUnique(email) {
  jQuery.get('/my-controller/test-email-uniqueness', email, function(json) {
    if (json.unique) {
      // Tell the user the email is in use.
    }
  });
}
```

That should do it. You'll need to work a little on the structure of the JSON document returned by the controller. **Do no return the entire user record** since this can give evil people access to stuff they shouldn't have access to. Preferably return something like `{ 'email': 'user@example.com', 'unique': true }`

Hope it helps.